# How to make an exception in a jinja2 template loop?

Tags: jinja2

I'm using a loop to generate blocks in an XML document, but I need to make an exception for the last block in the loop. I'd still like to use jinja2 to populate some of the variables in the last iteration, but there's a couple of variables that need to be different from the rest.

What's the best way to handle this situation? Is there any way to revise the output after it has been generated? Or should I just hard-code the last iteration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this...

```
{% for Product in Products %}
{% if Products | length == loop.index %}

<!-- your last item code -->

{% else %}

<!-- The other iterations -->

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!